# Grails 3 - Spring Rest Docs using Rest assured giving SnippetException when using JSON views

Tags: spring, rest, grails, grails-3.1, spring-restdocs

I am trying to integrate Spring REST docs with rest assured with Grails 3.1.4 application. I am using JSON Views.

Complete code is at https://github.com/rohitpal99/rest-docs

In NoteController when I use

```
List<Note> noteList = Note.findAll()
Map response = [totalCount: noteList.size(), type: "note"]
render response as grails.converters.JSON
```

Document generation works well.

But I want to use JSON views like

```
respond Note.findAll()
```

where I have _notes.gson and index.gson files in /views directory. I get a SnippetException. A usual /notes GET request response is correct.

```
rest.docs.ApiDocumentationSpec > test and document get request for /index FAILED
    org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException at ApiDocumentationSpec.groovy:54
```

with no message. Unable to track why it occurs.
Please suggest.

Full stacktrace

```
    org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException: The following parts of the payload were not documented:
{
  "instanceList" : [ {
    "title" : "Hello, World!",
    "body" : "Integration Test from Hello"
  }, {
    "title" : "Hello, Grails",
    "body" : "Integration Test from Grails"
  } ]
}
    at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.AbstractFieldsSnippet.validateFieldDocumentation(AbstractFieldsSnippet.java:134)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.AbstractFieldsSnippet.createModel(AbstractFieldsSnippet.java:74)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.TemplatedSnippet.document(TemplatedSnippet.java:64)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.generate.RestDocumentationGenerator.handle(RestDocumentationGenerator.java:192)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.restassured.RestDocumentationFilter.filter(RestDocumentationFilter.java:63)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.restassured.RestAssuredRestDocumentationConfigurer.filter(RestAssuredRestDocumentationConfigurer.java:65)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1574)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:159)
    at rest.docs.ApiDocumentationSpec.$tt__$spock_feature_0_0(ApiDocumentationSpec.groovy:54)
    at rest.docs.ApiDocumentationSpec.test and document get request for /index_closure2(ApiDocumentationSpec.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:442)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$1.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:70)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.executeAndRollback(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:67)
    at rest.docs.ApiDocumentationSpec.test and document get request for /index(ApiDocumentationSpec.groovy)
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for reply. I have added complete trace, there not much info  in SnippetException.

Comment: Thanks, but that's the stacktrace from Gradle when it fails the build due to the failing test. It's the stacktrace from the test itself that will be useful. It should be available in the test report

Comment: Sorry about that, updated with correct stacktrace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

REST Docs will fail a test if you try to document something that isn't there or fail to document something that is there. You've documented two fields in your test:

```
responseFields(
    fieldWithPath('totalCount').description('Total count'),
    fieldWithPath('type').description("Type of result")
)))
```

REST Docs has failed the test as some parts of the response haven't been documented. Specifically an `instanceList` array that contains maps with two keys: `title` and `body`. You can document those and the other two fields with something like this:

```
responseFields(
    fieldWithPath('totalCount').description('Total count'),
    fieldWithPath('type').description("Type of result"),
    fieldWithPath('instanceList[].title').description('Foo'),
    fieldWithPath('instanceList[].body').description('Bar')
)))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't care about potentially missing fields, you can use `relaxedResponseFields` instead of `responseFields`:

```
relaxedResponseFields(
    fieldWithPath('totalCount').description('Total count'),
    fieldWithPath('type').description("Type of result")
))
```

This won't fail the test if some fields are not mentioned.